# Open a dynamic form dynamically, winforms

Tags: winforms

My main class has following function:

```
sub openform(formnum as integer)

dim obj as Form

select case formnum
case 0
obj=new form0
case 1
obj=new form1
case 2
obj=new form2
case 3
obj=new form3
end select

obj.showdialog()

end sub
```

so the param '`formnum`' will be coming from command line args.

In the future I may have 1000 forms, so I need to write 1000 cases to open the required form.

Instead of that, is there any alternate way to open a form??

something like:

```
dim obj as form=application.findforms("form" & formnum)
obj.showdialog()
```

Comment: Welcome @Sandeep to Stack Overflow, you should use the  `{}` toolbox button to write your code parts. I did it for you right now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work?

```
Dim f As Form = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(Me.GetType().Assembly.FullName, "[namespace].form" & formnum), Form)
f.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Nope, can you give me the correct syntax
it says: overload resolutions failed with these arguments

Comment: it says system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle cannot be converted to windows.forms.form

Comment: You may have to call .Unwrap(). 
Activator.CreateInstance("[namespace].form" & formnum, True).Unwrap()

Comment: Sorry, it says could not load file or assembly.... (but the form actually exists in the application (with in the namespace))